# Exported xlsx file containing formulas appears to be broken in Protected View

Tags: .net, excel

I'm using Spire.xls for .net to export some reports. One template contains a column with formulas, the formula looks like this `=(B6-C6)`. The report opens in **Protected View** when opened from the browser, and all of the formulas in that column are resolving as `#VALUE!`, but when I enable editing, everything parses correctly.

Is this normal Excel behaviour? Is there anything I can do to prevent this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to incorrect usage of the markerdesigner, I needed to use the "apply styles" tag on the first cell of my row in order for it to process properly.